# starting tomcat as a service isn't logging in catalina.out

Tags: logging, tomcat6, ubuntu-9.10

Pretty simple:
When I run startup.sh or shutdown.sh information is logged into catalina.out When I run it as a service (i.e. `sudo service tomcat6 start/stop`) nothing is written to that log. Is it logging somewhere else? Is it logging at all? This is a fresh install of tomcat6 on ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found them. The service is logging them here:
/var/log/tomcat6/

Also, the service is using files under /etc/tomcat6 for configuration purposes.

Comment: If you used the standard installation that comes with the OS (via apt-get) then it re-organise the directories to match the UNIX standard